# Map elements of a list to their index in another list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am comparing two lists in Python.

`list1` is a superset of `list2`.

For the elements of `list1`, I want their index in `list2` (if present).

Here are two examples.

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = ['a','b']
```

The solution should produce `[0, 1]`.

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = ['b','a']
```

The solution should produce `[1, 0]`.

I attempted the following code, but it only works for the first example.

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = ['a','b']

pairwise = zip(list1,list2)
matched_index = [idx for idx, pair in enumerate(pairwise) if pair[0] == pair[1]]
```

This works. However, for the second set of sample data I get the wrong output `[]` instead of the expected output `[1, 0]`.

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = ['b','a']

pairwise = zip (list1,list2)
matched_index = [idx for idx, pair in enumerate(pairwise) if pair[0] == pair[1]]
print(matched_index) # prints []
```

Please suggest the way forward.

Comment: I reopened this question because the accepted answer from the marked duplicate produces the wrong result for OP's second example. The dupe produces `[0, 1]`, but OP wants `[1, 0]`.

Comment: In other words, OP wants to map the elements of `list1` to their indexes in `list2`.

Comment: What's the expected result with `list2 = ['c','a']`?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using a dictionary mapping the elements of `list2` to their index - assuming `list2` has unique elements.

```
>>> list1 = ['a','b','c','d']                                                                                            
>>> list2 = ['b','a']
>>> idx = {x:i for i,x in enumerate(list2)}                                                                            
>>> idx                                                                                                                
{'a': 1, 'b': 0}
```

Now you can issue

```
>>> [idx[x] for x in list1 if x in idx]                                                                                
[1, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `list2` is a subset of `list1`, you can construct a dictionary mapping and then use `dict.__getitem__` on values of `list2` to extract indices:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = ['a','b']
list3 = ['b','a']

d = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(list1)}

res1 = list(map(d.__getitem__, list2))  # [0, 1]
res2 = list(map(d.__getitem__, list3))  # [1, 0]
```

Comment: @timgeb, Yup, but `d.get` is functionally not equivalent. Since `__getitem__` guarantees you'll get an error if a `list2` value is not in `list1`.

Comment: Can do: ```d = dict(enumerate(list1))```, i find it nicer

Comment: @Aaron_ab no, that creates an index:value mapping, we need value:index.

Comment: @Aaron_ab, You would need `dict(map(reversed, enumerate(list1)))`. But I find the comprehension more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are unique elements in each list and `len(list1) >= len(list2)`

```
>>> list1 = ['a','b','c','d']                                                                                            
>>> list2 = ['d','a', 'f']
>>> print([list2.index(x) for x in list1 if x in list2])
```

Comment: While correct, note that this has time complexity O(len(list1)*len(list2)).